# Any similar command I can run in kubernetes as "docker run -ti --rm alpine ls /"

Tags: docker, kubernetes

In docker I can run a container with option `--rm` so that after the command finished the container is gone. For example, I can run the command below to list an Alpine container's root directories and it removes itself after running:

```sh
$ docker run -ti --rm alpine ls /
bin    etc    lib    mnt    proc   run    srv    tmp    var
dev    home   media  opt    root   sbin   sys    usr
```

How can I map a similar command in `kubectl`?

Comment: Did you look at the Kubernetes documentation that explains the commands and the available parameters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following command should do it:

```sh
kubectl run alpinepod --rm -it --image=alpine --restart=Never -- /bin/ls /
```

"kubectl run" command is similar to "docker container run" except that is run a pod instead of just container. [Create and run a particular image in a pod.] following is the explanation for the options we have used in above command (from kubectl run --help")

```
--image='': The image for the container to run. 
--rm=false: If true, delete resources created in this command for attached containers.
-i, --stdin=false: Keep stdin open on the container(s) in the pod, even if nothing is attached.
-t, --tty=false: Allocated a TTY for each container in the pod.
--restart='Always': The restart policy for this Pod.  Legal values [Always, OnFailure, Never].
we have used "Never" so that pod wont go for continuous reboot after the command completion
```

Comment: That looks about right, but SO usually prefers a bit more text around an answer. Could you add an explanation?

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer just added some explanation .

Comment: Gr8, `kubectl run` supports `--rm` as well.

Comment: Another important part is `--restart=Never`, I can figure out `--rm`, but I never though to put with `--restart=Never` together to get this command work as expect.

Comment: In fact I can write a kubernetes job to do a similar, it can be run with `kubectl apply -f`, but (1) the job pod is not disappeareda after finished (2) I can't run job with `kubectl run` command directly . Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Bill I agree , i have updated the answer covering the significance of "--restart=Never".Thanks for pointing it out :) .